# In Angular 4, how do I preserve query parameters in a redirected route?

Tags: angular

I have this route redirection in `app-routing.module.ts`:

```
{ path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full' }
```

Let's assume I have in `index.html` the line `<base href="/mysite">` inside `<head>` and the site is visited with URL `example.com/mysite?kiosk=true`.

How do I preserve the query parameter `kiosk=true` through the redirection above?

I can get the query parameters with this code inside `app.component.ts`, but *only* when the route redirect above is commented out:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.route.queryParams.first().subscribe((params: Params) => {
        console.log(params);
    });
}
```

How do I get it to work with the above redirect NOT commented out?
Is there an easy way to globally set "always preserve query parameters" or do I have to do some hack inside `app.component.js` that gets the query params, then redirects to '/home' only if the path is empty?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: No. I ended up just putting some redirect code in app.module.ts.

Comment: This question got me the tumbleweed badge.  :)

Comment: I ended up using a guard to get to the token before the redirect kicks in. I don't think guards are intended for this, but it works..

Comment: That's a shame. I would like to understand the exact same thing.

Comment: I don't understand why something that seems so fundamental is so difficult to find an answer on.

Comment: @JochemKuijpers Is it possible to add your solution as an answer. I really need it.

Comment: @Arashsoft I believe I ended up creating a service to query route parameters, instead of doing this directly from the component. Then I added a guard that executed before the redirect to store the route parameters in the service to overwrite the results that the service would give to the component. It's hack-y but it worked. I haven't worked with Angular since the 4.x releases though, so I don't know what has changed since then, and I as such I wouldn't be able to give a full answer now. Sorry.

Answer (score -1):

You can use for code nav `{ queryParamsHandling: 'preserve' }`. for DOM nav use `queryParamsHandling="preserve"` for angular 4 and up. other wise, use `{ preserveQueryparams: true }` from code and `[preserveQueryParams]="true"` from your DOM

Comment: Yes, but how do you do it in a redirect?